# Matching newline and any character with Python regex

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I have a text like

> var12.1
>   a
>   a
>   dsa
>   88
>   123!!!
>   secondVar12.1

The string between `var` and `secondVar` may be different (and there may be different count of them).

How can I dump it with regexp?
I'm trying something something like this to no avail:

```
re.findall(r"^var[0-9]+\.[0-9]+[\n.]+^secondVar[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", str, re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab it with:

```
var\d+(?:(?!var\d).)*?secondVar
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS4iV1/5). [`re.S` (or `re.DOTALL`) modifier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) must be used with this regex *so that `.` could match a newline*. The text between the delimiters will be in Group 1.

**NOTE:** The *closest match* will be matched due to `(?:(?!var\d).)*?` [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) (i.e. if you have another `var` + a digit after `var` + 1+ digits then the match will be between the second `var` and `secondVar`.

**NOTE2:** You might want to use `\b` word boundaries to match the words beginning with them: `\bvar(?:(?!var\d).)*?\bsecondVar`.

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

- `var` - match the starting delimiter
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:(?!var\d).)*?` - a tempered greedy token that matches any char, 0 or more (but as few as possible) repetitions, that does not start a char sequence `var` and a digit
- `secondVar` - match `secondVar` literally.

[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/TXzNJa)

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'var\d+(?:(?!var\d).)*?secondVar', re.DOTALL)
test_str = "var12.1\na\na\ndsa\n\n88\n123!!!\nsecondVar12.1\nvar12.1\na\na\ndsa\n\n88\n123!!!\nsecondVar12.1"
print(p.findall(test_str))
```

Result for the input string (I doubled it for demo purposes):

```
['12.1\na\na\ndsa\n\n88\n123!!!\n', '12.1\na\na\ndsa\n\n88\n123!!!\n']
```

Comment: `re.DOTALL` and `re.S` [are synonyms](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S).

Comment: I felt I missed something. Now, I think I finally got it.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag, with a regex like this: `var(.*?)secondVar`.  This regex would capture everything between `var` and `secondVar`.

Comment: `.*` is not correct as it is greedy, and will overmatch if there are more delimited sections.